# DependencyProperty, UserControl, CallBack fired once

Tags: c#, wpf

Im using a treeview control inside my usercontrol. Usercontrol is used in a MainWindow (just for test). DataContext of the MainWindow is my ViewModel.
In usercontrol code-behind i set some DependencyProperty and everythings work fine, eccept a property that doesn't fire the callback.
In ViewModel there is an ObservableCollection Tree. MyObject contains a property ObservableCollection Leafs. This is the tree structure i'm using to populate the TreeView.

If i pass Tree property to the usercontrol (usign a DependencyProperty Source), it works fine. I mean that if i change elements inside Tree in ViewModel, Source fires the notification and the TreeView is updated. 
If i pass Tree.Leafs.elementAt(0) CurrentTree to the usercontrol (using another DependencyProperty Root) the notification fires once only when the usercontrol is loaded. If i change CurrentTree, the notification in ViewModel works, but RootChanged() in UserControl is not raised. I don't understand why.

This is the code:
MainWindow

```
<DockPanel>
    <controls:TreeView Root="{Binding CurrentTree, Mode=TwoWay, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}">            
    </controls:TreeView>
</DockPanel>
```

ViewModel

```
    private MyObject currentTree;
    public MyObject CurrentTree
    {
        get
        {
            return currentTree;
        }
        set
        {
            if (currentTree == value) return;
            currentTree = value; 
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

UserControl code behind

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty RootProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Root", typeof(MyObject), typeof(TreeView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(RootChanged)));
private static void RootChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((TreeView)d).Root= (MyObject)e.NewValue;
}

public MyObject Root
{
    get
    {
        return (MyObject)GetValue(RootProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(RootProperty, value);
    }
}
```

TreeView (UserControl) xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControls.TreeView"
         x:Name="TreeViewUserControl"
         .....
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Root.Key, ElementName=TreeViewUserControl }" Height="16"/>
         .....
</UserControl>
```

The MainView DataContext is ViewModel, i suppose that the Datacontext of UserControl is inherited from MainView.
The TextBlock in UserControl is used for test the DependencyProperty.

This is the XAML Binding debug:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=14200498): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=14200498): Found data context element: TreeView (hash=49044892) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=14200498): Activate with root item ViewModel (hash=49218346)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=14200498):   At level 0 - for ViewModel.CurrentTree found accessor ReflectPropertyDescriptor(CurrentTree)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=14200498): Replace item at level 0 with ViewModel (hash=49218346), using accessor ReflectPropertyDescriptor(CurrentTree)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=14200498): GetValue at level 0 from ViewModel (hash=49218346) using ReflectPropertyDescriptor(CurrentTree): MyObject (hash=52380055)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=14200498): TransferValue - got raw value MyObject (hash=52380055)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=14200498): TransferValue - using final value MyObject (hash=52380055)
```

So, i don't understand why the DependencyPropertyCallback is fired once.

Comment: You don't need your callback actually. You're trying to set the property value second time - it's already set for you.

Comment: It seems also pointless to have a TwoWay Binding on the Root property. Does the control ever set that property itself?

Comment: As another note, it also looks odd to have a property as the backing "field" of another property. Change `private BsonTree currentTree { get; set; }` to `private BsonTree currentTree;`. And although perhaps obvious, but `NotifyPropertyChanged();` uses `CallerMemberNameAttribute`?

Comment: You should also consider to change the name of your UserControl class. `TreeView` is easily confused with the TreeView class in WPF.

Comment: @dymanoid  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(RootChanged) removed but still doesn't work

Comment: @Clemens, TreeView is a fake name used only for this post.  {get;set;} removed, binding Mode set to OneWay but still doesn't work. NotifyPropertyChanged() use CallerMemeberName.

Comment: So TreeView is only meant to confuse us? Really, change it, especially when it's just used for this post. Please also show us some code where you *actually* change the CurrentTree property.

Comment: It's a little bit hard to post the code, you right to ask, but tons of code to post. Maybe the problem is there. I can only say that the ViewModel raises the notification when CurrentTree property changes. If someone confirm that the DependecyProperty is well implemented, i'll dig in the classes behind the ViewModel.

Comment: The dependency property declaration seems ok. You may also keep the PropertyChangedCallback (without the re-assignment of the property) for debugging purposes, i.e. to set a breakpoint. The `set` method of the wrapper property won't always be called, e.g. if the the property value is changed by a Binding.

Comment: @Clemens this means that if i change CurrentTree value in ViewModel, there is no notification in set method of Root property in the UserControl code behind?

Comment: No, the setter isn't called when the property is set by a Binding (and some other sources). WPF calls `SetValue(RootProperty, ...)` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Code is a little bit complex then the code posted.
This is the structure:

1 Class Library Project with a class MyViewModel

2 UserControls Library Project with "MyTreeView"

3 Wpf Project used to test 1 and 2. MainWindow datacontext is MyViewModel from 1

The main problem wasn't with DP.

In Class Library Project i used a BaseNotify class inherited from all other classes. MyViewModel too.
Removing BaseNotify from MyViewModel and inheriting INotifyPropertyChanged directly, now everthing works fine!
I don't know why, but it work.

BaseNotify class:

```
public class BaseNotify : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```